# Eclipse Oxygen - Debugging Issue "Step Over"

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Since updating Eclipse from Neon to Oxygen I've an issue with the "F6 - Step Over" function while debugging my code. Each time I'll use "Step Over" and the current line contains a method call I'll get into the method (behaviour of "F5 - Step Into"). The same behaviour occurs when using the "Step over" - button. After stepping into the method I lost connection (e. g. when using  "F6 - Step Over" again) to the debugger and an error occurs: "*com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got an error code in reply:35 occurred creating step request*.".

A typical code line which causes the mentioned problem looks like:

```
Collection<Object> coll = getSomething(...);
...
...
private Collection<Object> getSomething(...) { ... }
```

Does anyone have the same issue and can give me a hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and found an answer to your question:

On the page https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/jdt.php#step-show-methodresult they introduced this new feature.
If you disable it, Step Over will work as always ;-)

go to Window - Preferences - Java - Debug and disable "Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow"

[image: problem view]

Why they enabled an experimental feature that disastrous is anyones guess...

Comment: For me this also avoids strong slowdowns using step over (as advertised) - I was using step return plus a breakpoint on the next line to survive - thank you.

Comment: I'd like to email you a pizza for saving my morning!

Comment: I only regret that I have but one upvote to give for this answer.

Comment: pizza and regrets indeed. "may be slow" what an understatement.